# Concrete Analytic Geometry of Polygonal Shapes

Tags: analytic-geometry, polytopes

I have a student who is interested in working on certain questions involving regular polytopes or regular polygons etc. He needs to find a reference which has analytic geometry of such things. In particular, how to realize such objects as solutions sets or parametrically. Or just generally some sort of analytic geometric presentation of such objects.

Thanks for any insights you may have on this somewhat vague question.

Comment: This one might be too advanced (depending on the student's level), but at least it's free: https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1684&context=cis_reports

Comment: @quasi I'll let him know. That might help.